# Why does my autoencoder generate the Anomalous image instead of the anomaly-free image?

Tags: deep-learning, encoding, decoding, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I really need help with this, I am working on an anomaly detector project using Autoencoder, the first part of the project is to build an autoencoder trained only on non anomalous images so when it is tested on anomalous images (images never seen), it will reconstruct the non anomalous image and then compare between the input image (anomalous image) and the output image ( reconstructed anomaly-free image) so I can visualize the loss. but in my case the autoencoder is always reconstructing the input image as it is, whether it is anomaly free or anomalous image, in my project the autoencoder is not supposed to reconstruct the anomalous images as they are ( data never trained on ). Can someone please tell me what I am missing..

My training dataset is composed of 10 RGB identical anomaly-free images
and my test dataset is composed of 1 anomalous image and 1 anomaly free image
you can find below the output of the autoencoder for the test images.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj8cz.jpg

here's my autoencoder architecture I was aiming to modify it for better reconstruction but I stopped when it started reconstructing the anomalous images instead of anomaly-free images

```
def architecture_MVTEC(input_shape=(128, 128, 1), latent_dim=100):

parameters = dict()
N_layers = 8
parameters["filters"] = [32,  32, 64, 64, 128, 64, 32, latent_dim]
parameters["kernel_size"] = [4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 8]
parameters["strides"] = [2,1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
parameters["padding"] = ["same" for _ in range(N_layers-1)] + ["valid"]

# Input
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = inputs

# Encoder
for i in range(0, N_layers):
    x = Conv2D(
      filters=parameters["filters"][i],
      kernel_size=parameters["kernel_size"][i],
      strides=parameters["strides"][i],
      padding=parameters["padding"][i])(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

# Decoder
for i in reversed(range(0, N_layers)):
    x = Conv2DTranspose(
      filters=parameters["filters"][i],
      kernel_size=parameters["kernel_size"][i],
      strides=parameters["strides"][i],
      padding=parameters["padding"][i])(x)
    x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)

# Output
x = Conv2DTranspose(
  filters=input_shape[2],
  kernel_size=(3, 3),
  strides=(1, 1),
  padding="same")(x)

outputs = x

# Autoencoder
autoencoder = Model(inputs, outputs, name="autoencoder")[![enter image description here][1]][1]

return autoencoder
```

enter image description here

here's the autoencoder's summary :

```
Model: "autoencoder"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 128, 128, 1)]     0         
                                                                 
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)        544       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu (LeakyReLU)     (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 32)        16416     
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 32)        9248      
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 64)        32832     
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 16, 16, 64)        36928     
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_5 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 128)         131200    
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_5 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 64)          73792     
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_6 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 8, 8, 64)          0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 32)          18464     
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_7 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 8, 8, 32)          0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)           (None, 1, 1, 100)         204900    
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_8 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 1, 1, 100)         0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTra  (None, 8, 8, 100)        640100    
 nspose)                                                         
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_9 (LeakyReLU)   (None, 8, 8, 100)         0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DT  (None, 8, 8, 32)         28832     
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_10 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 8, 8, 32)          0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DT  (None, 8, 8, 64)         18496     
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_11 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 8, 8, 64)          0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DT  (None, 16, 16, 128)      131200    
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_12 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DT  (None, 16, 16, 64)       73792     
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_13 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DT  (None, 32, 32, 64)       65600     
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_14 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_6 (Conv2DT  (None, 32, 32, 32)       18464     
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_15 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_7 (Conv2DT  (None, 64, 64, 32)       16416     
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_16 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_8 (Conv2DT  (None, 128, 128, 32)     16416     
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
 leaky_re_lu_17 (LeakyReLU)  (None, 128, 128, 32)      0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_transpose_9 (Conv2DT  (None, 128, 128, 1)      289       
 ranspose)                                                       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,533,929
Trainable params: 1,533,929
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Can you show what autoencoder.summary() output gives?

Comment: Your latent dimension need to be small in order for it to be an "information bottleneck", needed for it to learn a representation that will discriminate between trained data and any other input. Try a value of 2-10

Comment: Thank you so much for you quick reply ! I edited the post with the Autoencoder's summary ! 
I will absolutely try the model with a new bottleneck value and I will be back !

Comment: You have 1.5 million parameters and 10 training samples. Might want to switch to gray scale, half the input resolution, half all the kernel sizes. Remove all layers without downsampling (stride 1). Switch to DepthWiseSeparableConvolution

Comment: Hello again ! I made the changes you told me about except for the DepthWiseSeparableConvolution (it gave me an error I hope it doesn't make a big change), so I got 4 layers with the filters [32, 32,  64, latent_dim], kernal size [2, 2,  2, 2] and all the strides are equal 2 with a latent dimension equal 5, the number of parameters is 27,919 but unfortunately the autoencoder keeps generating the anomalous image.. if you think it could be another reason I can send you the complete code

Comment: Sorry, I meant half the number of filters, not kernel size. Kernel size should stay 3,3

Comment: You should start with just 2 latent dimensions. You need to show your training curve. Loss over time should drop to a really low value on the training data. And I would put in a validation set of a couple of anomalous and non-anomalous cases, and track their reconstruction errors over epochs

Comment: Btw, your task would be simpler if the images were aligned before going into the model. And maybe also histogram normalized. Alternatively, you can use data augmentation to introduce such invariances